# Get product attribute for Simple product in WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, php, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to get product attributes from product in WooCommerce, type product Simple product, some product can be as dropdown, but much options as radio button.

How I can do this? How it possible?

With variations I have no problem, but for simple I can't get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Loic's answer for an attribute of `pa_manufacturer`:

```
if ( get_post_type( $post ) === 'product' && ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() ); // Get the WC_Product Object
}

$product_attributes = $product->get_attributes(); // Get the product attributes

// Output
$manufacturer_id = $product_attributes['pa_manufacturer']['options']['0']; // returns the ID of the term
$manufacturer_name = get_term( $manufacturer_id )->name; // gets the term name of the term from the ID
echo '<p class="manufacturer">'.$manufacturer_name.'</p>'; // display the actual term name
```

Answer (score 6):

You will use the `WC_Product` method `get_attributes()` that returns an array like:

```
global $product;

if ( get_post_type( $post ) === 'product' && ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() ); // Get the WC_Product Object
}

$product_attributes = $product->get_attributes(); // Get the product attributes

// Raw output
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $product_attributes ); echo '</pre>';
```

It should work *(for real product attributes)*.

---

Now if you use some third party plugins, like product add-Ons for example, they add some custom fields to the product, but they are not product attributes…

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: This gets an array of all attributes, which can be used to get an individual attribute by replacing `print_r($product_attributes)` with something like `print_r($product_attributes['pa_color'])` however that only returns an ID of the term, so more would need to be done to get the term title from that ID.